# how to render image from nodejs to react js using axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, axios, render

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import axios from "axios";

import "./getForm.css";

class GetData extends Component {
  state = { posts: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8888/api/v1/user") //returns promise
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ posts: response.data });
        console.log("response:", response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("err:", err);
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Posts</h1>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>id</th>
              <th>name</th>
              <th>email</th>

              <th>mobile</th>
              <th>status</th>
            </tr>
            {this.state.posts.map((post) => {
              return (
                <tr key={post.id}>
                  <td>{post.id}</td>

                  <td> {post.name}</td>
                  <td> {post.email}</td>

                  <td> {post.mobile}</td>
                  <td>
                    <img src={post.image} />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default GetData;
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note:* Assuming you have the `image` URL's on your server response.

The `posts` state is being mapped before you receive the response from your server on the initial render. You can add a `loading` state which is set to `true` initially and after the `response.data` is set in the `posts` state, you can set `loading` to false.

You can then conditionally render the whole component based on this `loading` state like this.

Here is a link to a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-bartik-k9yk0?file=/src/App.js).

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

import axios from "axios";

class GetData extends Component {
  state = { posts: [], loading: true };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchUserData();
  }

  fetchUserData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8888/api/v1/user");
      this.setState({ posts: response.data, loading: false });
      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ loading: false });
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return "Loading";
    }

    return (
      <>
        <h1>Posts</h1>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>id</th>
              <th>name</th>
              <th>email</th>

              <th>mobile</th>
              <th>status</th>
            </tr>
            {this.state.posts.map((post) => {
              return (
                <tr key={post.id}>
                  <td>{post.id}</td>

                  <td> {post.name}</td>
                  <td> {post.email}</td>
                  <td> {post.mobile}</td>
                  <td>
                    <img src={post.image} />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default GetData;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add routes for your photos into Node.js public folder:

```
...
app.use('/photos', express.static(__dirname + '/public/photos'));
...
```

Then return image_url from http://localhost:8888/api/v1/user, the URL can be like http://localhost:8888/api/v1/photos/your_image_name.jpg

In your React:

```
...
<img style={{width:500, height:500}} src={post.image_url)} />
...
```